# Postgresql doesn't see models from Django(Heroku)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I'm currently working on Django project. Inside it I have an application 'Basketball'. That app have models such as 'Team', 'Player' and others. I've put my project on Heroku.

My problem is that I can access data in 'Basketball' models only by Django ORM. When I use raw SQL database doesn't see my tables.

To show an example, when I use Django shell of my project on Heroku

```
:~/$ heroku run python3 manage.py shell
>>> from Basketball.models import Player
>>> players = Player.objects.all()
```

**Variable 'players' indeed contains all instances of 'player' model.** When I explore database through Heroku command line

```
:~/$ heroku pg:psql
```

And when I list all tables

```
my_project::DATABASE=> \dt
```

I get following output:

```
List of relations
 Schema |            Name            | Type  |     Owner      
--------+----------------------------+-------+----------------
 public | Basketball_contract        | table | **************
 public | Basketball_match           | table | **************
 public | Basketball_matchstats      | table | **************
 public | Basketball_player          | table | **************
 public | Basketball_roster          | table | **************
 public | Basketball_team            | table | **************
 public | auth_group                 | table | **************
 public | auth_group_permissions     | table | **************
 public | auth_permission            | table | **************
 public | auth_user                  | table | **************
 public | auth_user_groups           | table | **************
 public | auth_user_user_permissions | table | **************
 public | django_admin_log           | table | **************
 public | django_content_type        | table | **************
 public | django_migrations          | table | **************
 public | django_session             | table | **************
 public | postman_message            | table | **************
```

But when I try to execute

```
my_project::DATABASE=> SELECT * FROM Basketball_player;
```

I get

```
ERROR:  relation "basketball_player" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM Basketball_player;
```

When I do makemigrations on my project on Heroku

```
:~/$ heroku run python3 manage.py makemigrations
```

It makes some migrations

```
Migrations for 'Basketball':
  0001_initial.py:
    - Create model Contract
    - Create model Match
    - Create model MatchStats
    - Create model Player
    - Create model Roster
    - Create model Team
    - Add field team to roster
    - Add field player to matchstats
    - Add field away to match
    - Add field home to match
    - Add field player_signed to contract
    - Add field team to contract
```

But when I try to apply them

```
:~/$ heroku run python3 manage.py migrate
```

That messages shows

```
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: staticfiles, mathfilters, django_countries, messages
  Apply all migrations: auth, sessions, admin, contenttypes, postman
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
  Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
  Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

Comment: You **must not** run makemigrations on Heroku. Do it locally, commit to git, and push to Heroku, then run the migrations.

Comment: @DanielRoseman thank you for your comment. But don't makemigrations command applies changes in database? I mean that I have different DB locally and different on Heroku.

Comment: No. `makemigrations` creates migration files on disk to be run with `migrate`. But on Heroku the disk is ephemeral, files do not persist between runs. As I said, you must create the migration files locally and upload to Heroku before running migrate.

Comment: Naturally, you are right. I was writing about `makemigrations` while was thinking about `migrate`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in PostgreSQL when you are using uppercase you have to embrace them with quotation marks so it should be

```
    SELECT * FROM "Basketball_player"
```

instead of

```
    SELECT * FROM Basketball_player
```

Comment: Quite an easy solution for such a long question :) Thanks! Still wondering about migrating, but I believe it's a different question.

Comment: if it is working you can [accept the question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Yes, I just checked. Thank you for your help. Also `makemigrations` issue was explained in comments under my post.